# Why an instance of List<> influences Instance of an ArrayList<>?

Tags: list, arraylist

I was testing this code in java and was wondering, why manipulating Instance List2 affects Instance List1?

As both prints print the same list including "Kiwi"

Is that because List2 is a List reference while list1 is an ArrayList Class instance?

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        
        ArrayList<String> List1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        List1.add("Apple");
        List1.add("Banana");
        List1.add("Orange");
        List<String> List2 = List1;
        List2.add("Kiwi");
        
        System.out.printf("List1 =%s\n", List1);
        System.out.printf("List2 =%s\n", List2);

    }
}
```

It would be great to get an explanation,
thanks!

Comment: They're both (separate) references to the same (single) `ArrayList<String>` object in memory.

Answer (score 0):

After this line...

```
List<String> List2 = List1;
```

... you have two variables pointing to the same `ArrayList` object.

Copying objects like lists is not trivial in Java.  The next step for you might be:

```
List<String> List2 = new ArrayList<>(List1)
```

(btw... you shouldn't capitalize your variable names)

That will behave more according to you expectations, I think.  If you define `List2` that way, only `List2` will get "Kiwi" added to it.  List1 will remain as it was ("Apple", "Banana", "Orange").

This is actually all you need, since you are putting String objects in your lists, and Strings are immutable in Java.

However, suppose you did something like:

```
ArrayList<MyComplexObject> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
list1.add(new MyComplexObject());
list1.add(new MyComplexObject());
list1.add(new MyComplexObject());
ArrayList<MyComplexObject> list2 = new ArrayList<>(list1);
```

... you will have two separate lists.  If you remove an element from `list2`, it will still be in `list1`.  However, if you *modify* an element in `list2`, **it will also be modified in `list1`.**  This is because, while the lists are separate objects, each one is pointing to the same instances of `MyComplexObject`.

If that behavior is not what you need, you need to do a "deep copy" of the List, which can be involved.